# comparing two lists elements in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have 2 lists which consider versions '2.0.0', Im comparing their element and get the list of [True, True, True] meanings, how can i take from list of [True, True, True] meanings, only one meaning True, or if it will be 1 False in that list, how can i get False, globally, i need to override magic methor **eq** and firstly Im trying to make it simple functionally. I expect to see True if they are equil, and False if something is different in those to lists.

```
import numpy

a = ['2','0','0']
b = ['2','0','0']

print(numpy.in1d(a, b))
if numpy.in1d(a, b) == [True, True, True]:
    print('equils')
```

Comment: In a comment you wrote: _Probably its not that i totally want, cause finally i need to compare versions like '2.0' and '1.0', '1.2.0' and '1.2.42', but im just trying to find ways to solve this problem_ Why not just compare the strings directly, like `'2.0.0'`?

Comment: Because next variants of versions will be like "('1.0.1b', '1.0.10-alpha.beta'),"
and I think that it better to separate strings to elements for then comparing the elements of list to what is more 1.0.1b or 1.0.10-alpha-beta

Comment: Are you doing this for learning purposes?

Comment: Its my courses homework, and the task is to override magic methods to compare version like i describe earlier

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by _override magic methods_ ?

Comment: For example, we have method __eq__ and we need to extand it to compare versions which are used in my task

Comment: Aaah, you're making a class, then.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)

```
numpy.all(a == b)
```

Comment: No problem, by the way, is `numpy.in1d` really what you want? Consider what happens if `b = np.array(['0', '2', 2'])`

Comment: Probably its not that i totally want, cause finally i need to compare versions like '2.0' and '1.0', '1.2.0' and '1.2.42', but im just trying to find ways to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Just use `all()`

```
if all(numpy.in1d(a, b)):
    print('equils')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would use numpy for that when a simple comparison of tuples will work out of the box

```
a = ('2','0','0')
b = ('2','0','0')

a == b # --> True


a = ('2','1','0')
b = ('2','0')

a == b # --> False
```